# Need to match the digit using regex by removing the initial zeroes

Tags: regex

I want to match initial character in the string by using regex to ignore the symbol "+" or "-" and consuming only 0 before any digit between 1 to 9.

Example

+004200
004200

Here, in the above example, I want to match only +4200 and 4200 respectively, by removing the initial zeroes.

I tried to solve it, by using the expression **^[^-+]\0+**, but it is not matching anything.   By analysing further, I figured that the expression [^-+] is still consuming the value. Can anybody suggest the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove optional zeroes and keep at least a single digit 1-9 after it:

```
([+-]?)0*([1-9]\d*)
```

**Explanation**

- `([+-]?)` Capture group 1, match an optional `+` or `-`
- `0*` Match optional zeroes
- `([1-9]\d*)` Capture group 2, match a digit 1-9 and optional digits 0-9

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nx0o7z/1).

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2

If there should be at least 1 zero present:

```
([+-]?)0+([1-9]\d*)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ngzTS1/1).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this:

```
/([+\-])*[0]*(\d+)/g
```

Your first capture group (`$1` or `\\1`) will contain the `+`/`-` if present, and the second group (`$2` or `\\2`) will contain the number without leading `0`s

As a note - you have to escape `-` with `\` when it's in a character group `[]` since it is used to denote sequences - `[a-z]` means all letters between `a` and `z`.

See this example here:

https://regexr.com/78tih

Comment: No need to escape `-` within character group `[]` if it's the first or last character in this group... same regex a little more simplified `([+-]?)0*(\d+)`